# Repeatable events php

Tags: php, loops

I have `array()` of week days to repeat my event.

```
[days_repeat] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )
```

1,2,3 are the events should be repeated every monday, tuesday, wednesday, but I have also

```
[start_date] => 2014-04-2
[end_date] => 2014-05-30
```

As you can see start day isn't the first day to repeat, if it was then was easier, just loop and make dates and break loop, when date is bigger than end date, **but maybe you can suggest me some good tactics to achieve this**

Days repeat array can contain only week day numbers and so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$daysRepeat = array(1,2,3);
$startDate = '2014-04-02';
$endDate = '2014-05-30';

//Convert to timestamps;
$startDateTstamp = strtotime($startDate);
$endDateTstamp = strtotime($endDate);

//Loop through days between start and end date
$tstamp = $startDateTstamp;
while($tstamp < $endDateTstamp) {

    //Calculate numerical representation of week day (1-7)
    $weekDay = date('N', $tstamp);
    if(in_array($weekDay, $daysRepeat)) {
        print date('Y-m-d', $tstamp) . "<br />";
    }
    $tstamp += (60*60*24);
}
```

Output:

```
2014-04-02
2014-04-07
2014-04-08
2014-04-09
2014-04-14
2014-04-15
2014-04-16
2014-04-21
2014-04-22
2014-04-23
2014-04-28
2014-04-29
2014-04-30
2014-05-05
2014-05-06
2014-05-07
2014-05-12
2014-05-13
2014-05-14
2014-05-19
2014-05-20
2014-05-21
2014-05-26
2014-05-27
2014-05-28
```

Answer (score 2):

First, convert `start_date` to a timestamp.

Then using php `date()` function as such :

```
echo date('w', $your_timestamp);
```

You get to know what day is the day of first_date, 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday).

Then just loop and go through your days checking if they match your array.

Answer (score 1):

if your data represents the days within a week (so first day of the week till the seventh day of the week), than you just need to check the current displayed day, if its the same "daynumber"

eg.

```
echo (new DateTime())->format("w");
```

will print

```
1
```

for monday

see the docs for more informations.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

so youll need only to check, if the current daynumber is in your repeat array!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with this code:

```
<?php
    $days_repeat = array(
        '1', // Monday
        '2', // Tuesday
        '3', // Wednesday
    );

    // first set timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    // Start date
    $date = '2014-04-02';
    // End date
    $end_date = '2014-05-30';

    while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
        // first find out which day of the week it is (0=sunday; 1=monday ... 6=saturday)
        $dateWeekDay = date("w", $date);

        // convert sunday from 0 to 7 if needed
        if ($dateWeekDay == 0) { $dateWeekDay = 7; }

        // check if $days_repeat has current day
        if (in_array($dateWeekDay, $days_repeat)) {
            // do action as this day is in $days_repeat
            echo date("Y-m-d"). ' is in $days_repeat';
        }

        // add +1 day and continue loop
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Conveniently, you are representing the day of the week according to the ISO-8601 specification. This means you can use PHP's built-in `date()` function with no additional translation to your format. That's nice.

Next, you need to figure out how to convert your `start_date` and `end_date` into a date format PHP can understand. It looks like [mktime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) is your best bet here - initialize the time elements to 0 if you don't care about them.

You can now iterate by day and if `date("N", $currentDay)` is in your array of wanted days, repeat the event on that day (whatever that entails). Here, `$currentDay` is the looped timestamp you're checking. `date("N")` returns the same ISO-8601 format day-of-week number as specified in the [manual page for date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).